# openlogitem various questions

Tags: java, xpages

Hy everyone,

I created a java classes that uses org.openntf.domino.logging.OpenLogItem to log events; 
code is like this:

```
    oli = new OpenLogItem();
    ...
    oli.logEvent(null, "Method : START", Level.INFO, null);
```

What I get in OpenNtf log db is that AgentName is "org.openntf.domino" and stackTrace report tens of lines not necessary and not wanted; so, my questions are:

- how can I set Agent Name to avoid "org.openntf.domino"?
- stack trace is not relevant; is it possible to remove it?
- I'm using org.openntf.domino.Document while 4° parameter is a LotusDocument (I think): how can I wrap LotusDocument from org.openntf.domino.Document?

TIA
Danilo

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent instead, if possible. If you want to get a handle on the OpenLogItem, use XspOpenLogUtil.getOpenLogItem(). See this blog post I wrote http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-openlog-logger-and-openntf-domino-api-core-structure/

For removing the stack trace, there's an xsp property available called xsp.openlog.suppressEventStack=true. See http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-openlog-logger-v4-0/. Personally I find the stack trace useful for identifying which phase something's occurring in. This may not yet be available in M4.5, but if you are using the version from GitHub, it is.

The fourth parameter should be an org.openntf.domino.Document. You'll never need a lotus.domino object for an org.openntf.domino method.

As soon as I make a change to anything in XPages OpenLog Logger project on OpenNTF, I'm also making the same amendments in OpenNTF Domino API.

Comment: 1/4
Thanks Paul for your answer but I got problems following your reply;
my method use a for loop, like the following : for (Document curDOC : _viewPartecipazioni.getAllDocuments() ) {..}
so, if I change initialization as 
'oli = XspOpenLogUtil.getXspOpenLogItem()' 
or 
'oli = new XspOpenLogItem();' 
the logEvent works and logged agentName is now the xPage name, but 
I get an error the 1st time execution is on 'for' line:

Comment: 2/4
23/07/14 13.14: Exception Thrown
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: violazione vincolo di caricamento: il loader "com/ibm/domino/xsp/module/nsf/ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader@1a5a1a5a" ha avviato precedentemente il caricamento per un tipo diverso con nome "org/openntf/domino/Document" definito dal loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@54155415"
translating from italian it is : javax.servlet.servletexception java.lang.linkageerror loader constraint violation
I got the same without initializing oli, using directly 'XspOpenLogUtil.logEvent

Comment: 3/4 
So, after many attemps I go back to version with 'oli = new OpenLogItem();'
and I try to use inside my loop the 4th parameter as in:
oli.logEvent(null, _strMessage, Level.INFO, (Document) curDOC); //I try also without casting ...
but I got the following error
.. HTTP JVM: OpenLogItem error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openntf.domino.impl.Document incompatible with lotus.domino.local.NotesBase
.. HTTP JVM: OpenLogItem error trace: 
.. HTTP JVM: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openntf.domino.impl.Document incompatible with lotus.domino.local.NotesBase

Comment: 4/4
Our server is 9.0.1 FP1
OpenLog feature is version 5.0.0.201403272259
org.openntf library are  .._1.0.0.20131118...
Let me know if I can supply you other info for troubleshoting.
Best regards - Danilo

Comment: I'm away from home and don't have my laptop, but I'll be back tomorrow evening and will try to reproduce and identify the cause.

Comment: Which version of the API do you have? I tested it in the latest test code and it works. My code was:
  Database db = Factory.getSession().getCurrentDatabase();
  View view = db.getView("allStates");
  Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
  XspOpenLogUtil.getXspOpenLogItem().logEvent(null, "Test message", Level.FINE, doc);
Demo database can be pulled from repo on GitHub https://github.com/paulswithers/org.openntf.domino-Demo-Database/tree/master

Comment: I use the following: org.openntf.domino.xsp_1.0.0.201311041650 // 
org.openntf.domino.plugin_1.0.0.201311041650

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the equvilant for notesbase from the org.openntf.domino API. youre trying to cast something that is from diff APIs. BR